# Problem when creating a weights column in the table

Tags: r, dplyr

Running regression with panel data on different geographical levels in the US and Euro area with weights that essentially look like this:

```
lm(log(POP25) ~ log(EMPLOY25), weights = weights, data = data)
```

The weights are the 2007 observations of POP25 for every grouping. This is the code and data for Europe. (For this dataset I don't experience any trouble.)

```
require(dplyr)
Data  <- Data  |>
    group_by(NUTS_ID)  |>
    mutate(weights = POP25[TIME==2007])
```

Data 1:

```
structure(list(...1 = 1:6, TIME = 2007:2012, NUTS_ID = c("AT", 
"AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT"), NUMBER = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), POP15 = c(5529.1, 5549.3, 5558.5, 5572.1, 5601.1, 5620.8
), POP20 = c(5047.1, 5063.2, 5072.6, 5090, 5127.1, 5151.9), POP25 = c(4544, 
4560.7, 4571.3, 4587.8, 4621.5, 4639), EMPLOY15 = c(3863.6, 3928.7, 
3909.3, 3943.9, 3982.3, 4013.4), EMPLOY20 = c(3676.2, 3737, 3723.8, 
3761.9, 3802.3, 3835), EMPLOY25 = c(3333.5, 3390.4, 3384.7, 3424.6, 
3454.4, 3486.4), weights = c(4544, 4544, 4544, 4544, 4544, 4544
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(NUTS_ID = "AT", .rows = structure(list(
    1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

However, I am not able to do the same code on data for US counties.

```
US_County  <- US_County  |>
    group_by(NAME) |>
    mutate(weights = POP25[year==2007])
```

Data 2:

```
structure(list(NAME = c("Ada County, Idaho", "Ada County, Idaho", 
"Ada County, Idaho", "Ada County, Idaho", "Ada County, Idaho", 
"Ada County, Idaho"), GEOID = c(16001, 16001, 16001, 16001, 16001, 
16001), year = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012), POP25 = c(205888, 
208506, 212770, 212272, 216058, 220856), EMPLOY25 = c(161385, 
160303, 152131, 155292, 155574, 164830), State = c("Idaho", "Idaho", 
"Idaho", "Idaho", "Idaho", "Idaho"), StateID = c(16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

When doing it with the last dataset I get this error message that I can´t figure out what means.

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing
  `weights = POP25[year == 2007]`.
x `weights` must be size 5 or 1,
```

I don´t know if there is anything wrong with the data. I have tried specifying the class so that everything should be equal across the datasets. I have also tried removing all NA observations, however with no luck.

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Are there any other ways to do the same?

Comment: your code isn't producing any errors for me. I think it might need a dataset with more than one county name to produce the error?

Comment: Do you have a 2007 value in every `NAME` group? If there is one missing you will get this error.

Comment: I think @SamR is probably right! Able to reproduce error that way.

Comment: Try replacing with `POP25[year==min(year)]` in the `mutate` call and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys!  I think you're totally right. When using your code @AndyBaxter it will run. Hopefully, it doesn't create biased estimates when using different years as weights. But that's another story. Thanks so much!